# Discord.js v13 sending error. It's alright in discord.js v12. How to fix it?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I upgraded my Discord.js v12 to v13 but it send to me this error

```
/home/discord/project/bloodmoon/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js:33
    agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
          ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
```

My node.js version is 16.7.0

```
node -v
v16.7.0
```

I think it's node.js problem it i can't find problem in that.
what's the problem?

Comment: Are you running your discord bot on another computer/server/shell than the one you used to get your node version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it by installing the latest version of NodeJS (16.11.0 at the time I'm writing this), not the LTS version (14.x.x)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this update the latest version of node. Currently v16.9.1